# HttpUrlConnection android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am new android developer.

I am trying this code for access data from my webserver....

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.mysite.net/LEDstate.txt");

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

        int data = isw.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            data = isw.read();
            //System.out.print(current);


            TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ledstate);

            t.setText(current); 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

But data is not appearing on Screen.There is no change in Textview.

I have checked Permissions they are ok.

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there any error? If so, post logcat output. And try debugging. Whats value in char current? (Check its not null)

Comment: No there error....but no display my data...display the default hello world!

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, but since you are catching all exceptions, the error is getting suppressed.

You cannot make network requests on Ui thread. Move the network operations to Asynctask.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `TextView` outside the while loop

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (data != -1) {
        char current = (char) data;
        data = isw.read();
        sb.append(current); 
}

TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ledstate);
t.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Along with this, pls check if its the case what @nandeesh has mentioned in the other answer

Comment: I do it but nothing...same problem...display the default Hello world! no my data....

Comment: did you move your code to a separate `Thread`? If it didn't work after that Pls remove the try: catch: block and provide the Exception logs.

Comment: If i put a button when click display my data?

Comment: use `AyncTask` to do network operations off the UI thread. This tutorial helps http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html